# Updating a remote media library plugin, wich breaks on php 8.1 update

Tags: php, media, remote

We use the (now abandonware) plugin Remote media libary, with the Flickr add-on.
It allows the user to see the wordpress photos and albums in the media library.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/remote-medias-lite/

The plugin contains the main remote media libraries folder,
and another folder called the flickr addon.

This works fine, but once we update to any php 8 version, the grey circle keeps spinning, and the photostream from flickr isnt loaded.
The plugin is built around guzzle, which handles a part of the flickr api connection  I believe.

Furthermore we get a lot of errors in the logs, just as these mentioned below,
would anybody on here know where to start on solving this issue ?

```
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property WPRemoteMediaExt\WPCore\hooks\ThemeScript::$isHooked is deprecated in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/loumray/wpcore/src/WPfeature.php on line 188

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property WPRemoteMediaExt\WPCore\hooks\AdminScript::$isHooked is deprecated in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/loumray/wpcore/src/WPfeature.php on line 188

Deprecated: Return type of WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Common\Collection::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Collection.php on line 294

Deprecated: Return type of WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Common\Collection::offsetGet($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Collection.php on line 299

Deprecated: Return type of WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Common\Collection::offsetSet($offset, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Collection.php on line 304

Deprecated: Return type of WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Common\Collection::offsetUnset($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Collection.php on line 309

Deprecated: Return type of WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Common\Collection::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Collection.php on line 50

Deprecated: Return type of WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Common\Collection::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Collection.php on line 45

Deprecated: WPRemoteMediaExt\Guzzle\Service\Description\ServiceDescription implements the Serializable interface, which is deprecated. Implement __serialize() and __unserialize() instead (or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary) in /wp-content/plugins/remote-medias-lite/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/ServiceDescription.php on line 11
```

Comment: You're going to have to troubleshoot each of those errors in the abandoned plugin's files one by one.  Warning though, as I have tried to fix another developers abandoned code in the past, sometimes you'll fix the first error and instead of getting rid of it, it'll add another half dozen.  
You may be better off building your own solution or looking for a replacement. Sorry.